# how to login to UPS.com with php cURL

Tags: php, curl, ups

I need a circa 2012 example of how to login to UPS using PHP cURL.  I am not closing the session between calls.  There are 3 pages to be fetched, 1) The login page 2) The password page and 3) the invoice page

I had it work before, however it doesn't anymore.  I deleted the cookie file and it worked for a while, then I get the message "Your current request has timed out due to inactivity. You will need to restart your request."  If I don't login within a window it times out even on a successful login.  I tried deleting the cookie file and starting again and that didn't work.  Any ideas how to make it so the timeout window is infinite?  Here's the code I have, credentials removed:

```
              $cookie_file_path = "/tmp/cookie.txt";
              // remove previous cookie
              if (file_exists($cookie_file_path)) {
            `rm -fr {$cookie_file_path}`;
              } 
            $login_url = 'https://www.ups.com/one-to-one/login';
            $password_url = 'https://www.ups.com/one-to-one/password';
            $invoice_url = 'upsDOTcomSLASHviewbillSLASHinvoices';
            $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0";

            $login_data = "sysid=null&lang=null&langc=null&method=null&returnto=null&loc=en_US&uid=<user_id>&rememberMe=1&next=Next&pm_fp=version%253D1%2526pm%255Ffpua%253Dmozilla%252F5%252E0%2520%2528windows%2520nt%25206%252E1%253B%2520wow64%253B%2520rv%253A10%252E0%2529%2520gecko%252F20100101%2520firefox%252F10%252E0%257C5%252E0%2520%2528Windows%2529%257CWin32%2526pm%255Ffpsc%253D24%257C1920%257C1200%257C1160%2526pm%255Ffpsw%253D%257Cqt6%257Cqt5%257Cqt4%257Cqt3%257Cqt2%257Cqt1%257Cswf%257Cpdf%257Cpdf%2526pm%255Ffptz%253D%252D5%2526pm%255Ffpln%253Dlang%253Den%252DUS%257Csyslang%253D%257Cuserlang%253D%2526pm%255Ffpjv%253D1%2526pm%255Ffpco%253D1";
            $password_data = "sysid=null&lang=null&langc=null&method=null&returnto=null&loc=en_US&password=<password>&next=Log+In&pm_fp=version%253D1%2526pm%255Ffpua%253Dmozilla%252F5%252E0%2520%2528windows%2520nt%25206%252E1%253B%2520wow64%253B%2520rv%253A10%252E0%2529%2520gecko%252F20100101%2520firefox%252F10%252E0%257C5%252E0%2520%2528Windows%2529%257CWin32%2526pm%255Ffpsc%253D24%257C1920%257C1200%257C1160%2526pm%255Ffpsw%253D%257Cqt6%257Cqt5%257Cqt4%257Cqt3%257Cqt2%257Cqt1%257Cswf%257Cpdf%257Cpdf%2526pm%255Ffptz%253D%252D5%2526pm%255Ffpln%253Dlang%253Den%252DUS%257Csyslang%253D%257Cuserlang%253D%2526pm%255Ffpjv%253D1%2526pm%255Ffpco%253D1";

            $headers[] = "Accept: */*";
            $headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
            $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $login_data); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.ups.com/myups/login'); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
            ob_start();
            $result = curl_exec ($ch);
            ob_end_clean();
            echo curl_error($ch);   // prints nothing if successful
            //curl_close($ch);


            //$ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $password_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $password_data); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $login_url); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
            ob_start();
            $result = curl_exec ($ch);
            ob_end_clean();
            echo curl_error($ch)        // prints nothing if successful
            //curl_close($ch);


            //$ch = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $invoice_url);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'));
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $invoice_data); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $password_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
            ob_start(); 
            $result = curl_exec ($ch);
            ob_end_clean();
            echo curl_error($ch);       // prints nothing if successful
            curl_close($ch);
```

I can't get past the first login page even after deleting and re-creating cookie file, as I get:

Your current request has timed out due to inactivity. You will need to restart your request.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: looks like it violates the ups terms of service to do this.

Comment: UPS does have an API for such things, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try connecting from another server. Maybe you got blacklisted.
2. Play with `CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT` or `CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE` curl options.
3. Visit login page before submiting the post data

Answer (score 0):

yes I was bored, but here is why you shouldn't be doing it.

1.2 f of UPS Technology Agreement:

> Automated Access. Without limitation, any access to the UPS Systems or
>   hosted UPS Technology by automated inquiry devices, robots, or
>   repetitive data gathering and extraction tools, routines, scripts or
>   other mechanisms with similar functionality that itself is not UPS
>   Technology licensed for such purposes hereunder is expressly
>   prohibited.

Comment: Ah, ok, didn't know.  Well, unfortunately I will have to do it manually then.  They don't have an API for this, btw.  They have a tracking and rating API, but they do not have an invoicing API.  I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I don't work for them, I wont tell them if you do it anyway :-)